# Where is the code to handle Paging when I drag and drop GridView and ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, objectdatasource

If I drag and drop a GridView and an ObjectDataSource onto a page, hook them up, pull in some data and let the controls handle everything automatically where is the code that tells the controls how to behave?

Answer (score 1):

The server controls that you add to an aspx files are represetations of classes in the .NET framework that contain all the logic which is relevant to the controls behavior.